# Qual é o erro nesta expressão regular?

Tags: javascript

Qual é o erro desta expressão regular. Já testei com outra função e a máscara funciona. Mas nesta para números com centavos, não funciona. Qual é o erro?

```
<html>  
<body>  
<script>  

function mascara(o, f) {  
obj=o;  
fun=f;  
setTimeout(execMascara(), 1);  
}  

function execMascara() {  
obj.value=fun(obj.value);  
}  

function soNumeros(v) {  
    var v = this;  

if(v.indexOf('.')==-1) {  
v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, "$1,00");  
    }  

v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{1})/g, "$1,$20");  
v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{2})/g, "$1,$2");  

return v ? "R$ " + v : 'Grátis';  
}  

</script>  

<form>  
<label="numero">  
Só número: <input id="numero" onkeypress="mascara(this,soNumeros)"/>  
</label>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>  


<html>  
<body>  
<script>  

function mascara(o, f) {  
obj=o;  
fun=f;  
setTimeout(execMascara(), 1);  
}  

function execMascara() {  
obj.value=fun(obj.value);  
}  

function soNumeros(v) {  
    var v = this;  

if(v.indexOf('.')==-1) {  
v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, "$1,00");  
    }  

v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{1})/g, "$1,$20");  
v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{2})/g, "$1,$2");  

return v ? "R$ " + v : 'Grátis';  
}  

</script>  

<form>  
<label="numero">  
Só número: <input id="numero" onkeypress="mascara(this,soNumeros)"/>  
</label>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: @rray já foi formatado. Ainda estou me interando com a formatação do stackoverflow.

Comment: Retira o escape \. de ambas as regex, testei sem eles e funcionou normalmente.

Comment: @Diego Felipe é para tirar os símbolos "\" e o "."? Tirei o "\" e continua aceitando letras.

Comment: Olha resposta do @Brunno, ela atende perfeitamente ao que você quer fazer.

Comment: @Diego Felipe  Vi, mas tem uma situação, até comentei lá. O usuário precisa digitar 00 para inserir valores apenas em reais. Se não digitar 00, o valor é alterado.

Comment: Não vejo problema nisso, se você checar grandes internet bankings, esses digitos funcionam desta forma, você vai digitando e precisa adicionar os zeros para "crescer" um valor. Desde que a mascara mostre ao usuário de que se ele digitar 120, vai formatar como 1,20 antes(como na solução do brunno), não tem problema. Deve-se atentar ao caso dele desligar o javascript, mas creio que uma tela de confirmação seria suficiente.

Comment: @Diego Felipe  verdade. Vou usar assim e faço uma observação no formulário para o usuário.

Answer (score 2):

O objecto `window` está sobrescrevendo o valor informado no campo de texto, veja a linha 16.

```
var v = this; //Está instrução não faz muito sentido
```

O objecto `window` não tem a função `indexOf()`.

Comment: coloquei com as alterações citadas por você. Confira, por favor no pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/JTf3PRJ5

Answer (score 2):

Para adicionar a mascara só com JavaScript e Regex, eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
document.getElementById('numero').addEventListener("keyup", mascara); //Pego evento de keyup ()

function mascara() {
    var v = this.value; //Pego valor
    v = v.replace(/\D/g, ''); //Valida se é numero
    v = v.replace(/(\d{2})$/, ',$1'); //Seto valores antes da virgula
    v = v.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1.');
    this.value = v != '' ? 'R$ ' + v : 'Grátis'; //Retorno seu valor com (R$) ou se estiver vazio seta para (Grátis) :D 
}
```

Segue um [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/hkoe6zm0/1/) da mascara :)

Comment: funcionou, mas tem um detalhe: se eu digitar 120 reais, vai me retornar 1,20. A função tem que aceitar a vírgula ou o ponto digitado pelousuário. Se o usuário digitar outro caracter que não seja a vírgula, não aceita no campo. Se digitar automaticamente, ou o usuário digita 00 no final ou vai alterar o valor.

Comment: Tem um caractere "*" que é chamado de lazy, alguma coisa assim para encontrar um caractere no campo de edição.

Comment: @AndréNascimento, então cara esse exemplo acima ele vai colocar a mascara de forma incremental, na minha aplicação ele atendeu legal, mas é sim possível algumas alterações para que aceite ponto ou virgula mais vai ter que mudar um pouco o funcionamento da regex .. Outro caso seria usar algum plugin, existem vários que fazem isso :D Mais que não quiser colocar jQuery no meio ai vale analisar a alteração na regex hehehe'

Comment: Brunno
@ preferi a regex, só fiz algumas mudanças, pois quando eu digitava 1000, o correto seria estruturar para 10,00, mas a regex colocava a vírgula assim: 100,0. Tinha parte da regex que inseria a "," após 3 números. Só fiquei com a última linha, que  é para inserir "," antes dos dois últimos números.